# List Schema : Title Field ID

Tags: list-definition

When creating custom List definitions, what should the ID value of the "Title" field be?

At one point I was told I should be using the OOTB ID (fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247) as it caused multiple Title fields to show up list, however recently I saw code that used different ID value for each list without issues.

Is there a best practice around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [SPBuiltInFieldId](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.aspx&ei=Qaw-Tt_GCszAgQet9cj_Bw&usg=AFQjCNEd2v6c9NXmPk3tGUDQ1B67yPjoGA&sig2=f1hXjQtKFFn3Dl0W3ezbnA) documentation and [Frodes awesome list of SharePoint Column Field IDs – for SharePoint 2010](http://aarebrot.net/blog/2010/06/frodes-awesome-list-of-sharepoint-column-field-ids-for-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 0):

I have always used the FA564 one, as the others are typically calculated fields that use this field as a basis.

Comment: James, I meant that recently I saw a devleoper using randomnly generated ID instead of the FA564 or any of the other calculated fields related to the Title field. 

Just trying to understand the if there are any side effects to just using a random GUID instead of the OOTB one.

I'm assuming the best practice recommendation would be to use the FA564...